# Excel: complicated SUMPRODUCT formula needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

I'm in search of a SUMPRODUCT formula, or a similar sort of formula which does the same thing. It should do the following:

1. On worksheet A it needs to ignore incorrect zipcodes, meaning
   zipcodes which do not consist of 4 numbers and 2 letters need to be
   ignored. It also needs to take into account that there sometimes are
   superfluous spaces behind the zipcode. And sometimes there is a
   space between the numbers and letters, sometimes there isn't. Just
   the 4 numbers and 2 letters need to be compared.
2. The correct zipcodes on worksheet A need to be compared with the
   zipcodes on worksheet B. If they match, then all the values behind
   the zip code need to be summed up. If there is another record
   starting with the same zipcode then these need to be added up as
   well.
3. Neither of the worksheets should need to be changed, since the data is generated frequently. The formula should be able to work on a third, separate worksheet. And it should work in Excel 2003.

EDIT: Added point 3.

I'll add an image to visualize what I mean. Hopefully someone can help me!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/557447/sum-of-vlookup-using-array-formula

Comment: Not really, he has to ignore spaces and incorrect data...

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you need to get 9 in B1 of Worksheet A? And is `1112BB` equivalent to `1112 BB`?

Comment: @pnuts Oh, I didn't notice the second one below. That would mean that the space should be ignored as well...

Comment: It will be simpler with some helper columns. Is that an option?

Comment: 1111AA should be 19, correct.

Comment: I'd prefer if neither of these 2 worksheets need any modification because in the real situation these are 2 separate spreadsheets and the summed up total would be listed on a third. So it would be great if it's just one formula that can be used for this.

Comment: Are there always 4 values following the zip code on worksheet B? Could there be more then 4 or less than 4?

Comment: In reality there are 12 values, one for each month.

Comment: And even though the sheets change frequently, can you set up the initial formatting of the sheet to use Excel Tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some helper columns, you could use something like this (open in new tab for larger version):

[image]

The formulae:

In B2 to remove spaces and hence get a 'clean' ZIP and check the length:

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))=6,SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),"")
```

In C2, to get the sum:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(LEFT(B2,4)*1),CODE(MID(LOWER(B2),5,1))>=97,CODE(MID(LOWER(B2),5,1))<=122,CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(B2)))>=97,CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(B2)))<=122),SUMPRODUCT($H$2:$K$8*($G$2:$G$8=B2)),""),"")
```

In G2, I used the same one as in B2:

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F2," ",""))=6,SUBSTITUTE(F2," ",""),"")
```

---

Without the helper, the formula becomes much longer because of repeating parts:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))=6,ISNUMBER(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),4)*1),CODE(MID(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")),5,1))>=97,CODE(MID(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")),5,1))<=122,CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))>=97,CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))<=122),SUMPRODUCT($H$2:$K$8*(SUBSTITUTE($F$2:$F$8," ","")=SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))),""),"")
```

Or

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(
        AND(
            LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))=6,                      ' Check length
            ISNUMBER(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),4)*1),         ' Check numbers
            CODE(MID(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")),5,1))>=97,   ' Check if letter
            CODE(MID(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")),5,1))<=122,  ' Check if letter
            CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))>=97,     ' Check if letter
            CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))<=122     ' Check if letter
        ),
        SUMPRODUCT(
            $H$2:$K$8*
            (SUBSTITUTE($F$2:$F$8," ","")=SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))),
        ""
    ),
    ""
)
```

---

Oops, forgot that `IFERROR` was not in 2003. The only reason why I used it was that `MID` would return an empty string and `CODE` would subsequently give an error. You can use the below instead which makes sure the string is 6 chars first:

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))=6,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),4)*1),CODE(MID(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")),5,1))>=97,CODE(MID(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")),5,1))<=122,CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))>=97,CODE(RIGHT(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))<=122),SUMPRODUCT($H$2:$K$8*(SUBSTITUTE($F$2:$F$8," ","")=SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))),""),"")
```

Comment: I'll give this formula a try as soon as I can. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Jerry, do you have any idea which of these functions is post-Office 2003 only? When I'm in Office 2007 and I try to save it, I'm getting a "One or more functions in this workbook are not available in versions prior to Excel 2007" error. It's not a huge dealbreaker, since I'm trying to get them to upgrade Office, but maybe the formula can be fixed easily before this happens?

Comment: @Zoke Added one without `IFERROR`. Using `IF(ISERROR()` will make the formula twice as long so I would move one main check outside to avoid making it too long, well, actually a few chars shorter!

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. If I try IF(ISERROR instead it says too many arguments for this function.

Comment: @Jerry I'm confused. How would I need to change the formula to get IF(ISERROR() to work in place of IFERROR?

Comment: @Zoke If you want to use `ISERROR()`... it will be twice as long. It will be like... `IF(ISERROR(longformula), "", longformula)`. I added one last formula in my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. And special thanks again to @Jerry for that great working formula!

Comment: FormulaDesk http://www.formuladesk.com will show you how complex formulas like the one above are composed. Essentially, it can automatically 'pretty-print' them for you, as well as pinpoint any errors in the formula. [Disclosure: I wrote FormulaDesk. I think it can definitely help visualize the proposed solution above.]

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a formula to validate Dutch postal codes

```
=AND(LEN(A2)=6; ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A2;4))); CODE(MID(LOWER(A2);5;1)) >= 97; CODE(MID(LOWER(A2);5;1)) <= 122; CODE(MID(LOWER(A2);6;1)) >= 97; CODE(MID(LOWER(A2);6;1)) <= 122)
```

0-9 = ASCII code 48 to 57
a-z = ASCII code 97 to 122 (lowercase)

In case you have a Dutch version of Excel, the formula would be:

```
=EN(LENGTE(A2)=6; ISGETAL(WAARDE(LINKS(A2;4))); CODE(DEEL(KLEINE.LETTERS(A2);5;1)) >= 97; CODE(DEEL(KLEINE.LETTERS(A2);5;1)) <= 122; CODE(DEEL(KLEINE.LETTERS(A2);6;1)) >= 97; CODE(DEEL(KLEINE.LETTERS(A2);6;1)) <= 122)
```